# Complex wordpress meta sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

Table structure (for example)

```
id(pk) | post_id |    meta_key     | meta_value
1            1       some_0_key_x      value1
2            1       some_0_key_y      value2
3            1       some_1_key_x      value3
4            1       some_1_key_y      value4
5            2       some_0_key_x      value5
6            2       some_0_key_y      value6
7            2       some_1_key_x      value7
8            2       some_1_key_y      value8
...
```

And so on

I want to get the following results

```
post_id | field_joiner |       x     |      y
   1       some_0_key       value1        value2
   1       some_1_key       value3        value4
   2       some_0_key       value5        value6
   2       some_1_key       value7        value8
...
```

And so on

**EDIT**
My query

```
SELECT  post_id, 
        substring_index(meta_key,'_',1) as field_joiner,
        max( case when substring_index(meta_key,'_',-1) = 'from' then meta_value end) as date_from,
        max( case when substring_index(meta_key,'_',-1) = 'to' then meta_value end) as date_to 
            FROM $wpdb->postmeta 
            WHERE meta_key LIKE 'kidum_%'
            GROUP BY post_id,field_joiner"
```

I need to add where clause to the `date_from` and `date_to`
How is it possible ?

Comment: You need to get it where? MySQL query, PHP, WP output? Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the same pattern and limited set of lookup i.e. x and y in this case, the following query for generating pivot data should do the trick

```
select 
post_id, 
substring_index(meta_key,'_',3) as field_joiner,
max( case when substring_index(meta_key,'_',-1) = 'x' then meta_value end) as x,
max( case when substring_index(meta_key,'_',-1) = 'y' then meta_value end) as y 
from table_name 
group by post_id,field_joiner;
```

Comment: Only need another hint please check my question edit

Comment: No you can not use alias in the where rather use them in having as `GROUP BY post_id,field_joiner having date_fro ...`